# C# Consuming XML API - No REST

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wsdl

I was wondering how to consume a XML Service, which states: "CarTrawler’s OTA Server does not expose a Web Services interface - i.e. no SOAP-discoverable WSDL. All messages are stateless and no session is maintained between calls.".

The service have targets URL’s defined in order to send the requests.

One possible request may be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA_VehAvailRateRQ
  xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 OTA_VehAvailRateRQ.xsd"
  Target="Test" Version="1.005">
    <POS>
        <Source ISOCurrency="EUR">
            <RequestorID Type="16" ID="#####" ID_Context="####" />
        </Source>
    </POS>
    <VehAvailRQCore Status="Available">
        <VehRentalCore PickUpDateTime="2016-04-01T07:00:00" ReturnDateTime="2016-04-09T19:00:00">
            <PickUpLocation CodeContext="####" LocationCode="71" />
            <ReturnLocation CodeContext="####" LocationCode="71" />
        </VehRentalCore>
        <DriverType Age='30'/>
    </VehAvailRQCore>
    <VehAvailRQInfo PassengerQty='3'>
        <Customer>
            <Primary>
                <CitizenCountryName Code='IE' />
            </Primary>
        </Customer>
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <ConsumerIP>999.999.999.999</ConsumerIP>
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </VehAvailRQInfo>
</OTA_VehAvailRateRQ>
```

Maybe using HttpClient?, as it has no WSDL and I guess the service isn't REST.

Comment: If it is HTTP it is REST.  Even SOAP over HTTP is REST.  And yes HTTPClient will work if it is an HTTP Service.

Comment: WSDL is not strictly necessary; see for example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823209/Consuming-SAP-PI-Web-Service-without-WSDL)

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem. WSDL is just metadata to help you figure out the kind of data you should send or receive. It doesn't mean that the service is not RESTful.

There are many tools that you can use to call a RESTful service. This is my REST client:
https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net

NuGet: Install-Package RESTClient.NET

You should try just doing a simple GET as a string and see what gets returned. If you post the Url of the API, I will try it.